# Get next element with specific class of clicked element with pure js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the the first element with a specific class which follow the element clicked with pure JS (no JQuery) in the following way but get el.nextSibling is not a function error. Initially I was using JQuery parents().next() but would like to do this with pure JS:

```js
const togglers = document.querySelectorAll('.toggler');
//console.log(togglers);
togglers.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    //const content = el.innerHTML;
    //console.log(content);
    el.nextSibling('.folder-content').style.display = 'block';
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="folder">
  <div class="toggler">Click me 1</div>
  <div class="folder-content" style="display: none">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
<div class="folder">
  <div class="toggler">Click me 2</div>
  <div class="folder-content" style="display: none">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The exact nature of the question is unclear: you might want to include the error _in the question_ (namely, "TypeError: el.nextSibling is not a function").

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`nextElement` is a property, not a function, so you don't use `()` with it. That said, using `nextSibling` can give you white space content which you don't want. Instead you can use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling):

```
el.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
```

```js
const togglers = document.querySelectorAll('.toggler');
//console.log(togglers);
togglers.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    //const content = el.innerHTML;
    //console.log(content);
    el.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="folder">
  <div class="toggler">Click me 1</div>
  <div class="folder-content" style="display: none">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
<div class="folder">
  <div class="toggler">Click me 2</div>
  <div class="folder-content" style="display: none">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. The HTML markup is a really simplified one. What can I do if I want to get nextElementSibling by a specific classname?

Comment: One way: `el.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('folder-content')[0].style.display = 'block';`

Comment: Got and understand it. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `while` loop to go searching for the first `nextSibling` that matches your criteria.

**edit:** As @j08691 points out, if your real code only cares about elements and not other node types, you can use nextElementSibling.

```js
const togglers = document.querySelectorAll('.toggler');
//console.log(togglers);
togglers.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var nextSibling = el.nextSibling;
    while (nextSibling) {
        if (
            nextSibling.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE
         && nextSibling.classList.contains('folder-content')
        ) {
            nextSibling.style.display = 'block';
            break;
        }
        nextSibling = nextSibling.nextSibling;
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="folder">
  <div class="toggler">Click me 1</div>
  <div>not this</div>
  <div>not this</div>
  <div class="folder-content" style="display: none">
    Lorem ipsum 1!
  </div>
  <div>not this</div>
  <div class="toggler">Click me 1.5</div>
  <div>not this</div>
  <div class="folder-content" style="display: none">
    Lorem ipsum 1.5!
  </div>
  <div>not this</div>
  <div>not this</div>
</div>
<div class="folder">
  <div class="toggler">Click me 2</div>
  <div class="folder-content" style="display: none">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
<div class="folder">
  <div class="toggler">Click me 3</div>
  <div>no folder content here!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion - I always find it much more legible when utilizing node types to compare to a property from the node object. For instance in your code you have it comparing nodeType == 1, when you could also state it as nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE

Comment: Better use `nextSibling.classList.contains('folder-content')` instead of `== 'folder-content'`. Else it wouldn't match `folder-content active` for example

Comment: Thanks for the suggested change, @zfrisch. I've edited my answer to include it.

Comment: And because SO won't let me tag two people at once, thank you also for the suggested change, @baao. I've edited my answer to include yours as well.

Answer (score 2):

I was building this answer while the others were coming in and, in the interest of variety and neat DOM programming, here's another way to skin this cat:

Here is the initial code that you have provided with a call to a separate function to do what was requested(find the next sibling matching a specified query string)

```
const togglers = document.querySelectorAll('.toggler');

togglers.forEach(function(el, i) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    searchNextSiblings(el, ".folder-content", function(ele) {
      ele.style.display = "block";
    });
  })
});
```

You'll notice that the function I am providing is called `searchNextSiblings` and it takes three parameters:

1. The Element that you would like to search from.
2. The Query String you would like the found element to match.
3. A function that receives the found element, and that you can use to manipulate it.

Here is the function itself:

```
function searchNextSiblings(ele, q, fn) {
    let flag = false;
    const nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
  ele.parentNode, 
  NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, 
  function(node) {
        if (ele.isSameNode(node)) flag = true;
        if (!flag) return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
        else {
            if (node.matches(q)) {
                flag = false;
                return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT
            };
        }
    });
    let currentNode;
    while (currentNode = nodeIterator.nextNode()) {
        fn(currentNode);
    }
}
```

And here is the annotated version:

```
    function searchNextSiblings(ele, q, fn) {
// we want to search from the first Element provided
// to properly search we will set our crawler to begin
// from its parent node, and when we reach the first Element
// we will begin searching for the Query String
// in order to do this we declare a flag to False
// when we reach the first Element we will set it as True
// This will let us know when we can search for the Matching Query

    let flag = false;
    const nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
      ele.parentNode, //root to search from
      NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, //set the iterator to search for elements
      function(node) { 
        if (ele.isSameNode(node)) flag = true;
//if we've found the first Element, set the flag to True
        if (!flag) return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
//if the flag is False, continue searching for first Element
        else {
//if we have found the first Element,
//we are now searching for the Element that Matches the Query
            if (node.matches(q)) {
//if we find a matching element
                flag = false;
//set the flag to false to stop the search
                return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT
//return the found node
            };
        }
    });
// the above declares the node iterator
// but does not start it up

    let currentNode;
    while (currentNode = nodeIterator.nextNode()) {
        fn(currentNode);
    }
//the above "starts up" the nodeIterator
}
```

```js
const togglers = document.querySelectorAll('.toggler');
togglers.forEach(function(el, i) {
 el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  searchNextSiblings(el, ".folder-content", function(ele) {
   ele.style.display = "block";
  });
 })
});

function searchNextSiblings(ele, q, fn) {
 let flag = false;
 const nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
  ele.parentNode, 
  NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, 
  function(node) {
  if (ele.isSameNode(node)) flag = true;
  if (!flag) return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
  else {
   if (node.matches(q)) {
    flag = false;
    return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT
   };
  }
 });
 let currentNode;
 while (currentNode = nodeIterator.nextNode()) {
  fn(currentNode);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="folder">
  <div class="toggler">Click me 1</div>
  <div class="folder-content" style="display: none">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
<div class="folder">
  <div class="toggler">Click me 2</div>
  <div class="folder-content" style="display: none">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```